# LCD's working principle

Tags: liquid-crystal

[image: liquid crystal's off and on]

In the image's information it says ''Liquid crystal device windows are in the group of electrically activated smart windows in which normal "off" condition of the glazing is a translucent milky white. When an electric current is applied, it turns clear.''

Shouldn't it be the reverse?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior research.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram you reproduce shows that the liquid crystal elements align in the presence of a potential difference - and when they do, they no longer scatter the light. This makes the window "clear".

Note that this is different than the situation in a monochrome LCD, where the liquid crystal elements are placed between crossed polarizers which have a surface texture that tends to align the crystals (weakly). This construction means that light, after passing through the first polarizer, is slowly rotated until its polarization is aligned with the second polarizer. This means the default state is "transmission"; and adding an electric field disturbs the crystal-to-crystal alignment and makes the element turn dark.

Whether the default state is "aligned" or "not aligned" depends on the structure of the molecules of the liquid crystal - but one could argue that a material whose default structure is "not aligned" doesn't really deserve the moniker "liquid crystal"...

I would argue that what you have here is a [suspended particle device or a polymer dispersed liquid crystal device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass#Suspended_particle_devices_.28SPDs.29) - this is different than a conventional LCD device. But for such devices the "on" state is the transparent one, as correctly stated in the image.